# Migrating large database

Tags: migration, sql-server-2008-r2

What is a quick way of migrating 75G database to the cluster? I tried to test the backup and restore and it took more than 2 hrs. Business owners won't accept the long outage. Any idea how I can make this fast or how to accurately do it? This is on SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: What do you mean by "to the cluster" - do you already have [MSCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Cluster_Server) deployed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to use a full backup to prepare, a differential to migrate.

First off, you do a full backup and restore to *prepare* the files on the new server disks, but use the [`RESTORE .. WITH NORECOVERY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526.aspx) option to allow more restores.

At the time of migration, you do a [differential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526.aspx) backup/restore. This is far quicker and you use `RESTORE .. WITH RECOVERY` this time.

Comment: touche sir ;) .. :D